# Variable value passed to report is not being printed

Tags: navision

So I'm trying to display my variable value in my report. But it prints in the message "Numerario" but in the report is not showing anything..

I changed the code and insert in the trigger below but the report is not printing the message in the page

Cust. Ledger Entry - OnAfterGetRecord()

```
Cust.GET("Customer No.");
FormatAddr.Customer(CustAddr,Cust);

IF NOT Currency.GET("Currency Code") THEN
  Currency.InitRoundingPrecision;

IF "Document Type" = "Document Type"::Payment THEN BEGIN
  ReportTitle := Text003;
  PaymentDiscountTitle := Text006;
END ELSE BEGIN
  ReportTitle := Text004;
  PaymentDiscountTitle := Text007;
END;

CALCFIELDS("Original Amount");
RemainingAmount := -"Original Amount";

Signature := ReportCertificate + CompanyInfo."Soft. Certificate Number" + ReportCode;

   IF "Cust. Ledger Entry"."Payment Method Code"= '' THEN
  PaymentMethod.INIT
  MESSAGE('Empty Payment Method Code');
END ELSE BEGIN
  PaymentMethodCode:="Cust. Ledger Entry"."Payment Method Code";
  PaymentMethod.GET(PaymentMethodCode);
  PaymentMethodDescription:=PaymentMethod.Description;
  Message('PaymentMethodCode %1',"Cust. Ledger Entry"."Payment Method Code");
END;
```

My var PaymentMethodDescription have the option "Include in dataset to true"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF "Cust. Ledger Entry"."Payment Method Code"= '' THEN
  PaymentMethod.INIT
  MESSAGE('Empty Payment Method Code');
END ELSE BEGIN
  PaymentMethodCode:="Cust. Ledger Entry"."Payment Method Code";
  PaymentMethod.GET(PaymentMethodCode);
  PaymentMethodDescription:=PaymentMethod.Description;
  Message('PaymentMethodCode %1',"Cust. Ledger Entry"."Payment Method Code");
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting variable on OnPostReport but trying to print it in the header from First record of the dataset. It’s just not there yet.

Comment: yes, I know but in the CustLedgEntry1.OnAfterGetRecord It prints empty the message and in the OnPostReport I have the payment method filled... where you think I can get this and print in the header?

Comment: If you want to print something in the report header you *must* `GET` it in appropriate trigger of the report. In your case it is `OnPreReport` most probably. Can't tell it without looking at the code.

Comment: If you want to chat in private I can show you the code.. In the OnPreReport the message returns an empty text